# How to fetch list of files in Pending changes in Jetbrains Team City?

Tags: teamcity

I need to retrieve the name of files which are shown in the Pending changes of Build. Is there any parameter or APIs available which can be used to fetch the list of files from the pending changes?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of files in Pending changes in Jetbrains Team City](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673387/how-to-get-list-of-files-in-pending-changes-in-jetbrains-team-city)

Comment: No need to ask duplicate question, you already asked one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673387/how-to-get-list-of-files-in-pending-changes-in-jetbrains-team-city